# Migaration code from Swift 2.3 to Swift 4

Tags: swift4, xcode9

Currently I am using Xcode 7.3 with Swift 2.3 . I received  a message from  Facebook Audiance Network that the SDK is going to be out dated and Ad will stop showing if I don't update the latest SDK (4.25 +). For that it needs minimum Xcode version 8 or higher.
These are the libraries in my pod file .

1. Alamofire
2. Side menu
3. Drop Down
4. Stripe

I need to change these libraries according to latest Swift syntax. So should I convert it first into Swift 3 or direct move into Swift 4 ?

Comment: Apparently someone asking the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/47281713/1423345